# Text box validation in javascript

Tags: javascript

How can I validate a text box, which only allow characters A-Z & a-z, Numbers, space, underscore and dash character ?   Text box should also not accept Spanish Accents and Letters like -á, -é, -í, -ó, -ú, -ü, -ñ, ¿, ¡.

Answer (score 0):

Use regex `/[^a-z0-9\s_-]/i` to check if there is other characters than Latin letters, numbers, space underscore or dash.

```
myString.test(/[^a-z0-9\s_-]/i);
```

Comment: @Aniket Yes. It's `\s`

Answer (score 0):

You should use a regular expression like this: `/^[\w-\s]+$/` to test if the input is correct.

```
^: from the begining
[\w-\s]: a combination of:
    \w: letters (latin), numbers and underscore
    - : dash
    \s: space
+: at least one time (at least one character long)
$: untill the end
```

**EXAMPLE:**

```js
var span = document.getElementById("span");

document.getElementById("input").oninput = function() {
  if(/^[\w-\s]+$/.test(this.value))
    span.classList.add("hidden");
  else
    span.classList.remove("hidden");
}
```

```css
#span{
  color: red;
}

.hidden{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input id="input"><span id="span">INVALID<span>
```